# Strange NPE when iterating over result of ClassLoader.getResources()

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, classloader

I would assume that the following code is safe, nevertheless I am getting an NPE while invoking `hasMoreElements()`. Any ideas what might be wrong?

I should add that I am using Java 1.7.0_55-b13 on Windows, 64 bit.

```
final List<URL> urls = new ArrayList<URL>();
final String plUri = "META-INF/plugin.xml";
Enumeration<URL> urlsEn =
   Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources(pluginsUri);
if (urlsEn != null) {
  while (urlsEn.hasMoreElements()) {  //  NPE happens here
    final URL u = urlsEn.nextElement();
    urls.add(u);
  }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.misc.MetaIndex.mayContain(MetaIndex.java:243)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:830)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$2.next(URLClassPath.java:273)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$2.hasMoreElements(URLClassPath.java:283)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$2.hasMoreElements(ClassLoader.java:1322)
    at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(CompoundEnumeration.java:45)
    at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(CompoundEnumeration.java:54)
    at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(CompoundEnumeration.java:45)
    at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(CompoundEnumeration.java:54)
    at com.github.jochen.afw.core.guice.GuiceComponentFactoryBuilder.getComponentUrls(GuiceComponentFactoryBuilder.java:256)
    at com.github.jochen.afw.core.guice.GuiceComponentFactoryBuilder.build(GuiceComponentFactoryBuilder.java:160)
    at com.github.jochen.afw.core.guice.GuiceComponentFactoryBuilderTest.testSuccessfullConfiguration(GuiceComponentFactoryBuilderTest.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ....
```

Comment: The problem is not that `urlsEn` is null - the NPE is thrown further down the stack so it looks like a bug..

Comment: What is the type of your thread context class loader?

Answer (score 1):

I hate to suggest your problem is something so simple, but could `pluginsUri` be `null` here?  At least in your code snippet, you create a `plUri` variable but then pass in an unmentioned `pluginsUri` to `ClassLoader.getResources()`.

From your stack trace, searching for "URLClassPath null pointer exception" uncovered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887509/nullpointerexception-when-declaring-new-imageicon) which looks to be the same stack trace.  In their case the argument to `getResources()` is clearly null.

Looking at the [Java 7 codebase](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/jdk7-b147/src/share/classes), we see that [`MetaIndex:243`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/jdk7-b147/src/share/classes/sun/misc/MetaIndex.java#l243) is:

```
if (entry.startsWith(conts[i])) {
```

And `entry` could be `null` at this line.  Looking higher up the stack, `entry` looks to be the `name` argument you passed to `ClassLoader.getResources()`.

This [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
public class ClassLoaderNPE {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      Enumeration<URL> urls = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResources(null);
      System.out.println(urls.hasMoreElements());
  }
}
```

replicates your stack trace (in Java 8, no less):

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

$ java -cp . ClassLoaderNPE
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.misc.MetaIndex.mayContain(MetaIndex.java:242)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:995)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$2.next(URLClassPath.java:288)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$2.hasMoreElements(URLClassPath.java:298)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$2.hasMoreElements(ClassLoader.java:1278)
        at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(CompoundEnumeration.java:45)
        at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(CompoundEnumeration.java:54)
        at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(CompoundEnumeration.java:45)
        at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(CompoundEnumeration.java:54)
        at ClassLoaderNPE.main(ClassLoaderNPE.java:9)
```

The [JDK](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResources-java.lang.String-) does not appear specify what happens if `name` is `null`. I've filed a bug to suggest fixing this behavior, or at least clarifying the documentation.  I'll update this post if/when Oracle accepts the issue.

**Update:** The report is tracked as [JDK-8136831](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8136831), and has been fixed in Java 9.